# how to use weka script in Groovy Console

Tags: groovy, weka

i have a script that want run in groovy console. my script is weka script like this:

```
data = (new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource("/home/username/weka-3-8-3/data/iris.arff")).getDataSet()
```

how to use weka script in groovy console?

Comment: Please add the errors you get. If you get class-not-found errors, have you tried @Grab-ing the deps?

Comment: i fond solution we must add weka.jar to groovy-starter.conf.